# contentEditable keyboard shortcuts

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any official list of keyboard shortcuts for browsers, that can be used in contentEditable `div` for text formatting?

I know three for Chrome (and maybe some other browsers): Ctrl+B, Ctrl+U, CTRL+I.

Where can I find this information? I've tried to find it, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: I believe that's system-dependent.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I found this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:HTML/Content_Editable, but it's very old info and not official.
And I've tested this keyboard shortcuts in Firefox - doesn't work.
So, I think it's not system-dependent.

Answer (score 5):

Bit late :) but just in case...

It's a bit dense, but this precisely answers your question: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/renderer/core/editing/editing_behavior.cc

TL;DR, there are a bunch of (honestly) kinda interesting and obscure things you can do, but in terms of the mainstream ^BIU is pretty much it.

(Aside - copying the entire relevant section of the code would turn this answer into quite the wall of text... I don't mind doing that if others think it's a good idea.)

Answer (score -2):

Those three and **Ctrl+P**, at least in Chromium
Ctrl+p will print just your contentEditable div with its formatting.